# Running cucumber features over different environments

Tags: selenium, automation, automated-tests, cucumber

I have a bunch of Cucumber features that are executing with Selenium in Java and JUnit. So far this code isnt version controlled and only runs on my DEV environment. But now we need to start bringing things up a level and versioning the automation code and running it in different environments.

I have various points in my code where it specifically mentions my environment. This will be things such as go to my DEV environment URL and do some Selenium stuff or connect to my DEV database. So I realise that I need to tidy up these methods so that the environment specific stuff gets passed in.

My question here is what decides what environment I'm wanting to run the checks in so I can then pass that environment specific stuff into these methods that need to know, such as URL names and DB connection stuff? I've seen mentions of using Maven properties for this and also seen a mention about writing a separate runner class using CucumberOptions. I'm wondering if there is a common approach to this that people use as it is no doubt a common task.

Hopefully this is the right forum for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, environment variables are used with configuration scripts, so you can pass and use the same via CLI arguments.

> we need to start bringing things up a level and versioning the automation code and running it in different environments.

This is quite helpful when working with CI servers (like Jenkins), which are usually employed to orchestrate and execute such jobs, that

> decide what environment ... to run the checks in ... then pass that environment specific stuff into these methods that need to know, such as URL names and DB connection stuff

I have found it relatively easy to switch behavior by passing in a system property at runtime, such as `mvn clean test -Denv=uat`. Well implemented pipeline will handle all this for you.

Comment: I now have my environment variables in config.properties so I'm now looking at the next step which is to pass in a property at run time with Maven. Struggling to find a good guide on how I do this task. Any ideas?

Comment: @Matt, trying to recall the exact setup, this is the basics https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cucumber/cucumber_command_line_options.htm and the Maven, i think this is the closest I can find http://toolsqa.com/selenium-cucumber-framework/run-cucumber-test-from-command-line-terminal/

Comment: Thanks mate. I'm getting there bit by bit I think. I'll get on to your links now as I'm a bit stuck again. Cheers for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a testconfig.properties

It should have

```
ENV=https://www............
DBURL=hostname and port
TESTDATA_FILE=\\file location
```

Just log them in the console saying running ENV is followed by the URL

You can have all urls listed in the properties file for your ENV.And you can comment the not required by using ** .

So,This will become configureable parameters in your framework with out code change.

Comment: Thank you for this. So I'm sure, you mean to create testconfig.properties through Maven, yes?

Comment: Yes buddy you can.